# How to populate other dropdownlist on selecting an option in a dropdownlist from database on click of a [show] button in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Hello Everyone I have been working on a project in which i have 4 dropdown list that are ddlpackage ,ddlcategory ,ddlsubcategory, ddlpackageprice respectively and a button named as Show 
Here is the image of front end :[Image of Front end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqVbv.jpg) 
Here is the image of the tables in the database [Image of tables from which i have retreived data to show in dropdownlist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zz5eg.jpg)
Now the problem i have is when a select an option from ddlpackage and click on show i am just getting the option on ddlcategory and then when again i click on show button i m getting option  on ddlsubcategory and then i have to again click on show button to get option on ddlpackage price.I want to show all option on single click of show button and on selection of dropdownlist ddlpackage Here is my C# code :

```
private String strConnection = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\PROJECT SEM6\Online Tours and Travels\App_Data\ToursandTravels.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindPackageDropdown();
    }
}
protected void BindPackageDropdown()
{
    //conenction path for database
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from package", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    con.Close();
    ddlpackage.DataSource = ds;
    ddlpackage.DataTextField = "packname";
    ddlpackage.DataValueField = "packid";
    ddlpackage.DataBind();
    ddlpackage.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
    ddlcategory.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
}
protected void ddlpackage_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int packageid = Convert.ToInt32(ddlpackage.SelectedValue);
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from category where Cat_id=" + packageid, con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    con.Close();
    ddlcategory.DataSource = ds;
    ddlcategory.DataTextField = "Cat_name";
    ddlcategory.DataValueField = "Cat_id";
    ddlcategory.DataBind();
    ddlcategory.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
}


protected void ddlcategory_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int categoryid = Convert.ToInt32(ddlcategory.SelectedValue);
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from subcategory where catid=" + categoryid, con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    con.Close();
    ddlsubcategory.DataSource = ds;
    ddlsubcategory.DataTextField = "subcatname";
    ddlsubcategory.DataValueField = "subcatid";
    ddlsubcategory.DataBind();
    ddlsubcategory.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
}
protected void ddlsubcategory_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    int subcategoryid = Convert.ToInt32(ddlsubcategory.SelectedValue);
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from package where packid=" + subcategoryid, con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    con.Close();
    ddlpackageprice.DataSource = ds;
    ddlpackageprice.DataTextField = "packageprice";
    ddlpackageprice.DataValueField = "packageprice";
    ddlpackageprice.DataBind();
    ddlpackageprice.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
}
```

Please do Help Sorry for my bad English... Thank You !

Comment: Your question doesn't seems correct, you are saying on a single click of 'Show' button you want to populate all drop down list (ddl). Which doesn't seems logical as one drop down is dependent on the previous.

Comment: so it cant happen? so i have to click on that button again and  again right? Can you provide some other solution all though if there would be no SHOW button it will fine for me can it be done without show button ? @Nadeem

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to click 'Show' button again and again. When the page load first time you are doing right things by loading the first drop down list, here is your code already doing this. 

`protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindPackageDropdown();
    }
}`

Now you just have to make sure on every drop down list, whenever you change the selection in the drop down list, the corresponding event will get fired e.g: ddlsubcategory_SelectedIndexChanged etc

Comment: ohk it was happening on click of button let me try without show button and i ll come back to you thank you for the tip  @Nadeem

Comment: i m not getting the expected one i mean i removed the show button and then when i m selecting an option from ddl package i m not getting option from ddlcategory please help ..@Nadeem

Comment: Put a debugger in below function and check it is getting fired or not when you do change item in ddl package, it should if not then there is missing event handler for this. If you are hitting breakpoint then check whether data is coming from DB or not, I hope you can find out reason why it is not filling the ddlCategory if your query is fine. `protected void ddlpackage_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{.......}
`

Comment: Thank you for your help .... I got it i Just needed to enable AutoPostBack="true" anyways thank you ! @Nadeem